# Spree Ecommerce System: Admin Account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I've installed and used a number of CMS systems written in ruby in the past, and on start up they all seem to follow the convention of pointing you towards creating an admin account. Refinery CMS does this, for example.

But the initial account you create when setting up Spree is simply a normal user account. How can I access the admin account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add /admin onto the end of your URL!

(If you're testing locally using the rails server, it will be

```
0.0.0.0:3000/admin
```

)

Log in with your default credentials that are set up during the initial installation of spree in the terminal/command line.